# Canvas doesn't get pointer events

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, uwp-xaml

I can't get why my canvas doesn't get pointer events. Below my code and a part of the XAML layout:
**XAML**

```
<Canvas
    x:Name="cPad"
    Canvas.ZIndex="99"
    Grid.Column="0" 
    PointerPressed="Pad_PointerPressed">
    <Rectangle 
        x:Name="rPicker"
        Width="24" 
        Height="24" 
        Stroke="Black" 
        Fill="White" 
        StrokeThickness="3"/>
</Canvas>
```

**C#**

```
private void Pad_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cPad.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(cPad).Position;
    Canvas.SetLeft(rPicker, point.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(rPicker, point.Y);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The problem that `rPicker` moves only if I click on `rPicker`... But I need to `Pad_PointerPressed` executes for any point on canvas. How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Canvas.Background` property to `Transparent` to enable `PointerPressed` events:

```
<Canvas
    ...
    Background="Transparent"
    >

    ...

</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try